# How to Free objects not owned by the form

Tags: delphi

I want to know what is best practice, what shouldn't, should or must be done when freeing objects that aren't owned by the form. 
Should I override the form's destructor and free the objects in there
or
Should I use the FormClose event and free the objects in there

Any comments are appreciated, maybe there is even a 3rd way that is better and I don't know about.

Looked in Google already, but either there are no comments about it, either I got the search question wrong.

Currently I have:

```pascal
procedure TmyForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject;
  var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Registry.Free;
  FileStream.Free;
  MemStream.Free;
end;
```

This works, just wondering if it is the right way to do it.

Comment: Default `Action` is `caHide`, so no, this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: Freeing the objects in the onClose event handler is the right place to do it, if the form is only every shown using ShowModal.

Comment: @nolas - Not causing any problems wouldn't make it right. You wouldn't want to keep track of unnecessary details, will I ever gonna show this form non-modal etc.. Semantically the right thing to do is to free the objects where it matches where you created it. OnClose would be right only if you created the objects in OnOpen, which is not possible.

Comment: @nolaspeaker: Even a form that is shown modally using `ShowModal` can be shown and closed multiple times during its lifetime, so in general `OnClose` is dangerous there too. But I understand that you are talking about the standard idiom `with TMyForm.Create do try ShowModal finally Free; end`, in which case `OnClose` *likely* is only called once. Still, "likely" isn't good enough, and you never know if a future programmer will use the form differently. So @Sertac is spot on with his remark. `OnDestroy` is the right place, even in cases where `OnClose` might work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The "right" way**

Typically, if a form has private fields that point to objects you create in the `OnCreate` handler (`FormCreate`, say) and that you want to be available for the lifetime of the form, you free them in the form's `OnDestroy` handler (`FormDestroy`, say):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Registry;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FRegistry: TRegistry;
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
    FList: TStringList;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FRegistry := TRegistry.Create;
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  FList := TStringList.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FList.Free;
  FBitmap.Free;
  FRegistry.Free;
end;

end.
```

This way they will be alive for the lifetime of your form.

In some cases, you might create the objects at later times -- or even have the variables point to different objects at different times -- but if they belong to the form, you typically free them with the form like in this example. (Recall that class member variables are always initialized, and that calling `Free` on a `nil` variable is perfectly safe, since `Free` basically does `if Assigned then Destroy`.)

**Why not `OnClose`?**

Using the `OnClose` handler for this is not quite safe, since it might be called several times during the form's life. And if you do `X.Free` in it, you will end up with `X` being a non-`nil` pointer to garbage.

For instance, the following code is a bug:

```
// BUG!! Don't do this!
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FList.Free;
  Action := caNone;
end;
```

Try closing the form twice.

Even if you don't use `caNone`, it might still be the case that this is a form that is opened and closed several times during its life; then you might not want to free all its objects the first time you close it. (And you *certainly* don't want to free them without setting the pointers to `nil`!)

**Bonus chatter**

If you let your field point to different objects at different times, you must make sure that you "repoint" the field in a safe way. For instance, the following approach is bad:

```
procedure RecreateFrog;
begin
  FFrog.Free;
  FFrog := TFrog.Create(ftBig, clRed, 123);
end;
```

The reason is that the constructor `TFrog.Create` might fail (raise an exception), in which case you'll end up with `FFrog` being a non-`nil` pointer to garbage. Instead, a safer way is

```
procedure RecreateFrog;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FFrog);
  FFrog := TFrog.Create(ftBig, clRed, 123);
end;
```

in which case `FFrog` will be a `nil` pointer if the new frog object cannot be constructed. And of course, in situations like this, you always test that `FFrog` is assigned every time you want to use the current frog.

Of course, there are other ways of doing things, and sometimes you have constructors that you know never fail, etc. The basic rule is that you should know what you are doing, and that the code should be guaranteed never to leak any resources, access dangling pointers, etc.

Comment: Why would you use OnCreate and OnDestroy rather than constructor and destructor?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No particular reason. Both approaches make sense. (For new Delphi programmers, `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` are likely somewhat more accessible, though, since they get help from the IDE in creating these event handlers.)

Comment: I've never really bought into these events because now you have to learn two different ways to do the same thing. Because at some point we all write classes that aren't derived from TForm.

Comment: @David: That's very true. (But of course there isn't anything "wrong" with those events, and I suspect they are used slightly more frequently when it comes to forms.)

Comment: I agree that there is nothing wrong with using these events, but then you did say that they were the "right" way and I was wondering if you had a reason for preferring them.  But it's fine.

Comment: Thanks, that was really the anwer I was looking for.

Comment: @Carl - In that case consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.